# Is the integral closure of a henselian local domain of dimension $1$ again local?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local domain of dimension $1$. Let $\overline R$ be the integral closure of $R$ in the field of fractions $Q(R)$.
If $R$ is henselian, then is $\overline R$ also a local ring  ?

Thoughts: According to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04GH , if $\overline R$ were moreover module finite over $R$, then $\overline R$ would be a product of local rings, and then $\overline R$ being an integral domain would imply it is local. However, $\overline R$ would be module finite over $R$ if and only if the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion $\widehat R$ is reduced (see Theorem 4.6 of the book https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-181), so I do not see if this approach will work (unless of course we assume $R$ is complete, then we are done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, without restriction on dimension. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BQ0.

Comment: To follow up; if $R$ is a henselian domain, then by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C24, we have that $\overline{R}$ is a local ring since the number of minimal primes of $R^h$ is the same as the number of maximal ideals of $\overline{R}$, correct?

Comment: @walkar: Yes, indeed.